# Friendly URL using .htaccess and PHP "include"

Tags: regex, apache, .htaccess, mod-rewrite, url-rewriting

I have very little experience with PHP and using .htaccess, though I would like to create SEO-friendly URLs. I have scoured the internet and Stackoverflow searching for a problem similar to mine. I have tried multiple solutions but have had no luck and I am constantly met with errors.

So I have decided to create my own, although I am aware there may be a correct solution out there for me, I have been unable to find it.

This is how my URL currently appears `www.site.com/?p=example`
I would like it to appear as `www.site.com/example`

My .htaccess file is set up like so
`RewriteBase /
RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} !^www\.
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ http://www.%{HTTP_HOST}/$1 [R=301,L]`

My `index.php` file is set up like so http://puu.sh/ix8vV/33ff702e21.png

Help would be greatly appreciated as I have been trying this for hours to no avail.

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You will need an additional router rule to forward all non-file and non-directories to `index.php` with a parameter `p`:

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /

RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} !^www\. [NC]
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ http://www.%{HTTP_HOST}/$1 [R=301,L]

# If the request is not for a valid directory
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
# If the request is not for a valid file
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteRule (.+) ?p=$1 [L,QSA]
```

Comment: Thanks for the response. But this just redirects all URLs back to the home page and not the appropriate pages